# Match start of list to timestamp

Tags: r

I have data which I have identified rolling sums (using `rollapply` function), and then identified the max rolling sum for a given timeframe. The `rollapply` function creates a new vector as expected and works perfectly. Now, I have tried figuring out how to match the max sum, with a timestamp in the main data frame. I have tried adding the `rollapply` vector as a new column but it is 'n' rows short, dependent on the width of `rollapply`. If anyone has suggestions as to how I can match the max value of `totals` to another column, I would be greatly appreciative.
Working example below

Script

```
test_data <- read_excel("test.data.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)

totals <- rollapply(test_data$Var, FUN = sum, width = 3)
```

Dataframe

```
Row    Time      Var
1      11:29:00  16
2      11:29:01  15
3      11:29:02  50
4      11:29:03  4
5      11:29:04  38
6      11:29:05  22
7      11:29:06  21
8      11:29:07  31
9      11:29:08  12
10     11:29:09  50
11     11:29:10  1
12     11:29:11  38
13     11:29:12  42
14     11:29:13  18
15     11:29:14  50
```

Output

```
totals
[1] 81 69 92 64 81 74 64 93 63 89 81 98 110

max_totals <- max(totals)
 
max_totals = 110
```

In the example provided above, I'd like to find out where the rolled sum for `max_totals` starts in the time column.

Comment: Can you give a small but complete example and show expected output based on that? Say 10-15 rows with rolling window width of 3?

Comment: Have added the working example. Hopefully it shows what I am trying to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the position where the sum of maximum sequence starts, it is better to use `rollsum` with `align = 'left'` and with `fill = NA` you will have the length same as your dataframe which you can add as a column.

```
test_data$totals <- zoo::rollsum(test_data$Var, 3, fill = NA, align = 'left')
test_data$totals
#[1]  81  69  92  64  81  74  64  93  63  89  81  98 110  NA  NA
which.max(test_data$totals)
#[1] 13
```

So row number 13 is where the maximum sequence starts.

Comment: This works a treat. Many thanks.